# Matching training and testing datasets

Tags: cross-validation, matching

This is more a general question on machine learning in general, but I have two datasets ~75k rows of patients and 100 columns (call it `training` and `testing`)--each column is either a numeric predictor corresponding to how many times they've visited a specific physician, or a factor (two examples are Gender and 10-year age bins). There are also two outcome arrays `training.obs` and `testing.obs` that correspond to how many days each patient has spent in the hospital.

Let's say I wanted to train a linear model `model <- lm(training.obs ~ ., data=training)`, and cross-validate it with the testing set by

```
testing.pred <- predict(model, testing)
```

and take the RMSE of `testing.pred` and `testing.obs`.

The two datasets are greatly different, in terms of factor ratios (i.e. a larger proportion of males in the training set), and distribution of numeric predictors. Would it make sense to match these two datasets by sampling `training`, or will I lose model accuracy because I'm excluding rows? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: By not having more resolution for the age variable, you may run the risk of having outcome heterogeneity within age bins, not to mention discontinuities in predicted values.

Comment: Yeah, not having a continuous age predictor will affect model accuracy greatly. I wonder though, whether model accuracy would be improved by matching the training to the validation dataset.